# How to refresh a particular div on button click in angular

Tags: angular

How to refresh a particular div on a button click?

*my component.html*

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>    
<div style="background-color:yellow; height:100px; width: 100%;">
Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</div>
<p>
<button (click)="refresh()" type="button">Refresh page</button>
```

here is my stackblitz link

*https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-refresh-function-bgtjik?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts*

Comment: Why do you want to update div? and what you will expect.

Comment: Try : 
refresh(): void {
    this.name = 'Angular is Refreshed';
  }

Answer (score 1):

```
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  Inject,
  Renderer2,
  OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  content: string;
  div: HTMLElement;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.div = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('div');
    this.content = `
      <div style="background-color: red; height:120px; width: 100%;">
        My refreshed div here!
      </div>
    `;
  }

  refresh(): void {
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.div, 'innerHTML', this.content);
  }
}
```